# Query insert a record in sql server table like 2013040900001

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

How do insert a record in sql server 2005  table with formatted date and appended with auto incremented numeric value?

For example if today's date `2013-04-09 12:05:44.640` then I am able to format it like `20130409` using  `convert(varchar, getdate(), 112)`.

But I want to insert a record like `2013040900001` then next would be `2013040900002`, `2013040900003` and so on.

Comment: You insert field as NUMBER or VARCHAR or DATE?

Comment: It's usually better to store the components in separate columns and only *actually* combine them during output/formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good solution for generating system-wide auto-incrementing numbers is via a table designed for the task:

```
CREATE TABLE [AutoInc]
(
   [Number] INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
   [Col1] CHAR(1) NOT NULL
);
```

Then insert a value into the table and immediately remove it with a ROLLBACK:

```
BEGIN TRAN;
INSERT INTO AutoInc VALUES ('A');
ROLLBACK TRAN;
```

This ensures no space is used (the table will always be empty) but will create the number (because values generated by the IDENTITY attribute do not participate in the transaction). You can then obtain the incremented value using the SCOPE_IDENTITY() function and append it to your date:

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (yourcol) VALUES (convert(varchar, getdate(), 112) + RIGHT('000000000' + CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS VARCHAR(10)), 10));
```

Comment: But when I truncate table value goes i as NULL

Comment: Yes, that's right. Why do you want to truncate the table? It is always empty.

Comment: ok..but if i insert  4 -5 records for test and if i truncate it then it starts from last auto incremented value. Means if i insert 4-5 records then last record would be 2013040900005 then if I truncate and again insert then it get starts with same 2013040900005 then 2013040900001,2013040900002,2013040900003,2013040900004,2013040900005 like then 2013040900005 will get repeat in sequence

Comment: Are you calling SCOPE_IDENTITY() immediately after truncating the table? That won't work. After truncating the table you must insert a new row before you can obtain the next number, which, after truncation, will always be 1

Comment: I am not able to run this query from JSP